# Delegated functions not working outside of UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the Startscream Websocket framework. Everything works fine as long as I keep all of the code in a `UIViewController` as seen [here](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/blob/master/examples/SimpleTest/SimpleTest/ViewController.swift). But as soon as a create a wrapper class for Startscream all of the delegated functions stop working. Also my local websocket server is not getting a connection.

How can I get the code working inside a wrapper class?

*MyService.swift:*

```
import Starscream

public class MyService: WebSocketDelegate {
    var socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:3900/websocket")!)

    func connect() {
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
        print("Connecting")
    }

    // MARK: Websocket Delegate Methods.

    public func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {
        print("websocket is connected")
    }

    public func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {
        if let e = error {
            print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("websocket disconnected")
        }
    }

    public func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        print("Received text: \(text)")
    }

    public func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocket, data: Data) {
        print("Received data: \(data.count)")
    }

    // MARK: Write Text Action

    @IBAction func writeText(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        socket.write(string: "hello there!")
    }

    // MARK: Disconnect Action

    @IBAction func disconnect(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if socket.isConnected {
            sender.title = "Connect"
            socket.disconnect()
        } else {
            sender.title = "Disconnect"
            socket.connect()
        }
    }

}
```

*ViewController.swift:*

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let service = MyService()
        service.connect()
    }

}
```

Comment: the way you're initializing your web socket in your viewController is different

Comment: @ReinierMelian how is it different exactly? I am calling connect on MyService that does the delegation + connection

Comment: in your ViewController you're using  `var socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8080/")!, protocols: ["chat", "superchat"])` in your custom class you're using `var socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:3900/websocket")!)` the protocols are missing in your custom class initialization I don´t know if can be related to your issue

Comment: @ReinierMelian you are correct, unfortunately adding them doesn't make a difference :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to `Service` in `ViewController` was not stored anywhere so as soon as the function was run it was cleaned up. This is how I fixed it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var service = MyService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        service.connect()
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Good catch on that one

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your code, it can be an endpoint issue, or WS is not allocated somehow. I have same code with Starscream working in Swift 3, here is the main part of my class.

```
class ConnectionManager {
    private var savedSocket: WebSocket?
    fileprivate var socket: WebSocket {

        if let saved = savedSocket {
            return saved
        }

        let wsURL = URL(string: UserDefaultsManager.wsURLString)!

        savedSocket = WebSocket(url: wsURL)

        return savedSocket!
    }

    func startSession() {

        if (socket.isConnected) { return }
        socket.headers = headers
        socket.delegate = self

        socket.connect()
    }

    func endSession() {

        if (socket.isConnected) {
            socket.disconnect()
        }

    }
}

extension ConnectionManager: WebSocketDelegate {
    func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket) {

    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocket, error: NSError?){
        if let e = error {
            log.error("websocket is disconnected with ERROR: \(e.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            log.error("websocket disconnected")
        }

    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocket, text: String){

    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocket, data: Data){

    }
}
```

My code is not a best practise for sure, but it works without any problem. Try to use my version, maybe it will work for you.

Comment: Can you also paste the code on how you use ConnectionManager?

Comment: It will be hard enough. I'm using MVVM and the app has separated managers for registration, userdefaults, etc. Also my connection manager is allocated inside an appModel singleton. 

But using ConnectionManager is not a big deal, just like this:
let manager = ConnectionManager()
manager.startSession()